# Create intermediate table manually in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, many-to-many

I have an excel that contains three tables, table_a, table_a_b and table_b.

table_a
id | name

table_b
id | product

table_a_b
id | a_id | b_id

I've created those tables manually and gathered the data to the DB through csv. My models file looks like this

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'As'

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Bs'

class AB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'AsBs'
```

I have a huge problem here, I cannot access to all objects B from a particular object A.

Two Questions:

1) Is my approach (creating the intermediate table manually?) good?

2) Is there a way to get all objects of B of A following my approach?

Comment: You can access all `B` objects through `a.ab_set.filter()`

Comment: it throws the same error, a object has no attribute ab_set

Comment: Nope. I've just checked locally. `a_obj = A(name='test'); a_obj.save(); a_obj.ab.set.all()`

Answer (score 0):

You have here a M2M relationship, django provides a great API to do all that you want here.

You can visit its documentation about M2M fields [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) where explains with details the way to build a m2m with an intermediate model (table)

Here [M2M through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) documentation